# php while inside for loop, using strlen

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop, strlen

The following is a code block that's working fine as regards getting the data I want.
Don't laugh, it's probably inefficient, but I'm learning :)
What I want, is to use the $totalLength variable, to stop gathering data when the $totalLength is, say 1500 bytes/characters (ideally, ending on a full word, but I'm not looking for miracles!). Anyway, the code:

```
$paraLength = 0;
$totalLength = 0;
for ($k = 0; $k < $descriptionValue->length; $k++) {        //define integer k as 0, get every description using ($k = 0; $k < $descriptionValue->length; $k++), increment the k loop (to get only 14 elements, use ($k <= 13))
$totalLength = $totalLength + $paraLength;
echo $totalLength." Total<br />";
$descNode = $descriptionValue->item($k)->nodeValue;       //find each description element
$descNode = trim($descNode);        //trim any whitespace around the element
$descPara = strip_tags($descNode);        //remove any HTML tags from the elements
$paraLength = (strlen($descPara));        //find the length of each element
//if (preg_match('/^([0-9 ]+)$/', $descPara)) {       //if element starts with numbers followed by a space, define it as a telephone number
//    $number = $descPara;
//    fwrite ($fh, "\t\t".'<div id="tel">'.$number."</div>\n");        //write a div with id tel, containing the number                                                                      
//}
//else
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{4,}/', $descPara)) {        //if element starts with at least 4 uppercase characters, define it as a heading
    $heading = $descPara;
    $heading=ucfirst(strtolower($heading));       //convert the uppercase string to proper    
    fwrite ($fh, "\t\t".'<div id="heading"><h4>'.$heading."</h4></div>\n");        //write a div with id heading, containing the heading in h4 tags                                                                     
}
else if (preg_match('/\d*\.\d{1,}[m x]/', $descPara)) {       //if the element contains any number of digits followed by a dot, at least one further digit and the letters m x, define it as a heading based on it containing room measurements (this pattern matches at least two number after the dot \d*{2,}}
    $room = $descPara;
    fwrite ($fh, "\t\t".'<div id="roomheading"><h4>'.$room."</h4></div>\n");       //write a div with id roomheading, containing the heading in h4 tags
}
else if (preg_match('/^Disclaimer/i', $descPara)) {        //if the element contains the word Disclaimer, define it as such
    $disclaimer = $descPara;
    fwrite ($fh, "\t\t".'<div id="disclaimer"><h4>'.$disclaimer."</h4></div>\n");        //write a div with id disclaimer, containing the heading in h4 tags
}
else if (strlen($paraLength<14 && $paraLength>3)) {       //when all else fails, if the element is less than 14 but more than 3 characters, also define it as a heading
    $other = $descPara;
    fwrite ($fh, "\t\t".'<div id="other"><h4>'.$other."</h4></div>\n");        //write a div with id other and the heading in h4 tags
}
else {
fwrite ($fh, "\t\t\t<p>".$descPara."</p>\n");       //anything else is considered content, so write it out inside p tags
}
}
```

$totalLength counts nicely, but when I tried to put a while statement in there, it just hung. I tried putting the while statement before and after the for, but no joy. What am I doing wrong and how best to solve this one?

FYI $descriptionValue, is data parsed from HTML using DOM & xpath, the while I tried was while($totalLength <= 1500)

Comment: It would be nice if you indented your code ;-)

Comment: And where did you want to put a while statement? IN where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what You want:

```
if ($totalLength > 1500) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution because it means no word breaks, but it can mean considerable over-run. I just tested it on one example and because the last paragraph in the loop was quite long, it meant the overall code returned 1913 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a condition inside your `for` loop. It will jump outside the loop as soon as the condition evaluates to true.

```
// for () { ...
if ($totalLength > 1500) {
    break;
}
// }
```

Basically, `break` ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure. You can find more about PHP's control structures in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).

Comment: Thank you bth, this works to a degree. As mentioned in my response to Alvar, it can mean a result considerably more than 1500 characters. I really need to get my head around modern programming languages :D. I learned on Gosub-Return, Goto and For-Next in Sinclair Basic! Once this project is complete, I will study hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete the for and add

```
$k = 0;    
while ($totalLength <= 1500 || $k < $descriptionValue->length)
```

and inside the loop you increment the value ok $k

Comment: I like the sound of this, as I'd like to replace that for loop with while, however, I couldn't get your suggestion to work. I put your suggestion in place of the for statement and $k++ inside every else. Could you give me an example of how you see it working, please?